# Spring 3.1 ConfigurableWebApplicationContext properties @Value not resolving

Tags: spring, properties

I need to add a bunch of Properties backed in the DB at start up time.
To test the whole thing works, I started with this (the ds.username property below comes from catalina.properties. It's there just to verify I don't break anything):

```
public class PropertiesInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableWebApplicationContext> {
@Override
public void initialize(ConfigurableWebApplicationContext ctx) {
try {
    props.put("hello", "goodbye");
    MutablePropertySources propertySources = ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources();
    propertySources.addFirst(new MapPropertySource("dbProps", props));
}
catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have a @Controller and I'm doing this:

```
@Autowired
Environment env;
@Value( "${hello}" )
public String hello;
@Value( "${ds.username}" )
public String un;
...
```

So, when I print those, 'hello' and 'un' are empty but the env.getProperties actually return the right values.

Why?

Thanks

Gerardo Blanco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${...}` properties are not enabled by default, you need to declare [`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) as a bean in order to enable them.

`Environment` works out of the box because it doesn't require special configuration.